# Can't set disk not readonly before cleaning

Tags: powershell

I need to select one of the four disks connected to the virtual machine. But when I chose the disk in the beginning, Powershell told me that the disk was read-only. How can I access the drive to clean it up and then create a new volume?
Here is my code:

```
Write-Host "Hello, this is a disk cleaner programm."
Write-Host "Choose a disk:"
$(Get-Disk | Where-Object {$_.BusType -eq "SATA"} | Select-Object Number).Number

Write-Host "`nWhich disk you want to clear?"
$diskNumber = Read-Host 
Write-Host "`nAre you sure?`nAll data will be disapeared. [Y/N]"
$option = Read-Host 
if ($option -eq "Y" -or $option -eq "y") {
    $disk = Get-Disk | Where-Object {$_.Number -eq $diskNumber}
    Set-Disk -Number $diskNumber -IsReadOnly $false -IsOffline $false
    $disk | Set-Partition -IsReadOnly:$false -IsActive:$true
    $disk | Clear-Disk -RemoveData -RemoveOEM -Confirm:$false
    New-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -DriveLetter T -UseMaximumSize
    Format-Volume -DriveLetter T -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "Lab5Part2Task8" -Confirm:$false
    Set-Partition -DriveLetter T -IsActive $true

    Repair-Volume -DriveLetter T -OfflineScanAndFix
    Get-Volume -DriveLetter T
}
else {
    break
}
```

Here are some of the errors:

```
Clear-Disk : The disk has not been initialized.
C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Scripts\Lab5\DiskCleaner.ps1:13 знак:13
+     $disk | Clear-Disk -RemoveData -RemoveOEM -Confirm:$false
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk) [Clear-Disk], CimE 
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 41000,Clear-Disk
 
New-Partition : The disk has not been initialized.
C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Scripts\Lab5\DiskCleaner.ps1:14 знак:5
+     New-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -DriveLetter T -UseMaximumS ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk) [New-Partition], C 
   imException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 41000,New-Partition
```

When I tried to initialize it, turn it on and run the script again, it said that the disk was not initialized. Then I decided to get the disk into a variable and pass it to the pipeline to the appropriate commands instead of explicitly specifying the disk number, but nothing happened

Comment: you cannot clear the entire disk,  only a partition.  See : https://www.computroon.co.uk/2022/09/26/delete-a-partition-with-windows-powershell-command-prompt-or-terminal/?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

You get the wrong way. Firstly, you have to initialize the disk as PowerShell advices you. Secondly, when the disk are initialized, you shouldn't set it.

```
    Initialize-Disk -Number $disk.Number -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false
    Set-Partition -Number $disk.Number -IsReadOnly:$false -IsActive:$true
    Clear-Disk -Number $disk.Number -RemoveData -RemoveOEM -Confirm:$false
    Initialize-Disk -Number $disk.Number -PartitionStyle GPT -Confirm:$false
    New-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -DriveLetter T -UseMaximumSize
    Format-Volume -DriveLetter T -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "Lab5Part2Task8" -Confirm:$false
    
    Repair-Volume -DriveLetter T -OfflineScanAndFix
    Get-Volume -DriveLetter T
```